# Parent container view doesn't change its size automatically

Tags: ios9, xcode7

I'm making an app and it uses storyboard. In a storyboard, I use a container view and it has some child view controllers and UIViews inside. when changing of the child view counts, I expect that the container view size will be changed automatically but actually not work on ios9 devices.

**Summary:**

- building at xcode 6.2, working(the container view size's changing automatically)  on ios8 and ios9 devices.
- building at xcode 7, working on ios8 but not working ios9 devices.

I don't know whether it's the problem of xcode7 or ios9.

Comment: Post your code please.